# cant get token from laravel passport with authorization_code flow

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth, laravel-passport

im using laravel passport and i want to get a token like this
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens-converting-authorization-codes-to-access-tokens

this is the code in my controller

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://passport-app.test/sso/oauth/token', [
           'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
           'client_id' =>env( 'CLIENT_ID'),
          'client_secret' =>env( 'CLIENT_SECRET'),
          'redirect_uri' =>env( 'REDIRECT_URI'),
          'code' => $request->code,
        ]);

        return $response->json();
```

but im getting an error

```
  "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.",
    "hint": "Cannot decrypt the authorization code",
    "message": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."

``
```

Comment: Share more code of contoller, model and request api for check the issue

Comment: hi @Armin Jaberi table `oauth_client` have the correct values and the url?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.